# How to delete a Lightning Web Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, vs-code

I'm trying to delete new Lightning Web Component without any luck.

I've tried to find it in Dev Console, but as you know it doesn't support Lightning Web Components yet. Another way I've tried to delete my lwc in VS Code and just deploy source to sandbox, but it still there in my sandbox org and I can see it in Lightning App Builder and when I try to retrieve source I see this error

```
ERROR:  Cannot read property 'fileName' of undefined.
```

But as mentioned here this should be fixed tomorrow https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/33

So for now I have it in org but don't have in VS Code.

Is there any sfdx command something like

```
sfdx force:lightning:lwc:delete -someflag lwcName
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you try this?
`sfdx force:source:delete -m LightningComponentBundle:componentName -r`

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I have this error ERROR:  The LightningComponentBundle named *my lwc name* was not found in the workspace.

Comment: whats your version of SFDX cli?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal everything is up to date. 
@salesforce/plugin-generator 1.0.1 (core)
@salesforce/sfdx-trust 2.0.1 (core)
builtins 1.0.0 (core)
salesforcedx 45.0.12 (pre-release)
sfdx-cli: 6.53.0-67a9cbb60c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have already set up Visual Studio Code and installed the necessary extensions:
[image: Salesforce VS Code Extensions]

It is as easy as right click the folder in VS Code to delete > SFDX: Delete From Project and Org

[image: SFDX: Delete From Project and Org]

Note: If you accidentally renamed your LWC in VS Code and pushed it into your org (e.g. Renamed "LWC_Eample" to "LWC_Example"), the old LWC "LWC_Eample" will still be visible in your SFDC org but not present in your VS Code.

If this happens, go to your VS code project, Right Click your "Manifest > Package.xml" > Retrieve Source in Manifest from Org.

Presto, your old LWC "LWC_Eample" will appear in VS code. Then you can proceed to `SFDX: Delete From Project and Org`

Comment: nice update, thanks

Comment: It's worth observing the `sfdx` commands this plugin runs in your terminal. You can do more with the `sfdx` command than with this VSCode only plugin.

Comment: @JanWerkhoven I've been seeing alot of answers that just post "sfdx force:.." but none really give an example on how to execute it. If I try execute those commands I always get error

Comment: You first need to install the sfdx binary on your device. On Mac, open your terminal and type: `brew install sfdx` and after that you should be able to run `sfdx --help`.

Comment: When I try this delete method, I'm getting an error `Warning  destructiveChanges.xml  No LightningComponentBundle named: myLWCfolder found`. I'm not sure how to create the bundle. I've retrieved the source from org using my manifest which references the LWC component already, but the error persists.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure that you have the most updated CLI version. On your terminal or command line use this:

```
sfdx force:source:delete -p <path-to-the-component-folder-on-your-machine>
```

It will ask you if you are sure, type y. And there you are.

Comment: I'm trying to delete the component from a Production org, getting the following error: "INVALID_OPERATION: testLevel of NoTestRun cannot be used in production organizations."  Any ideas on how to change the testLevel used behind the scenes for this SFDX delete command?  I don't see a command parameter for it in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_source.htm?search_text=change%20target%20org#cli_reference_delete)